# Differential operators (how to derive)

Tags: calculus

Let $T_v$ be a translation by $v$ (i.e. $T_v(x,y)=(x+v_x,y+v_y)$).

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function (i.e. have derivatives of all orders).

We define the following differential operator : $P_x(f)(v)=(\frac{d}{dt}(f(T_{(t,0)}v))(0)$
(evaluated at t=0).

I don't know how to derive this expression, can someone please help ? (The translations should be with a 1x2 vector and not 2x1, but I don't know this notation in tex).

Comment: You've given a definition - what is there to derive?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I wish to get an expression like in Giuseppe answer

Comment: You're lucky that Giuseppe was able to read your mind and figure out what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have by your same definition $$P_x(f)(v)=\left.\tfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(T_{(t,0)}v)=\left.\tfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(v_x+t,v_y).$$
Applying the chain rule for the derivation you get
$$(P_xf)(v)=((\partial_x f)(v),(\partial_y f)(v))\cdot(1,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(v).$$
I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about how you used ? thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, it really does help

Comment: Does this mean that if we were to evaluate at a different $t$ we would get the same result ?

Comment: No, $$\left.\tfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t}f(T_{(t,0)}v)=((\partial_x f,\partial_y f)(T_{(t,0)}v))\cdot(1,0)=(\partial_xf)(T_{(t,0)}v)$$

Comment: hmm, where did I go wrong ? I did: $F(t)=f(x(t),y(t))$ where $x(t)=x+t,y(t)=y\implies x'(t)=1,y'(t)=0\implies{P_{x}(f)(v)=(\frac{d}{dt}(f(T_{\begin{pmatrix}t\\
0
\end{pmatrix}}v))|_{t=0}=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}0)(v)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}v}$.